# Autofocus after free entries in MagicSuggest

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I am using MagicSuggest Plugin for Multiselect input box with free entries and dropdown.

I am allowing expandonfocus:true to show the dropdown automatically when the element got focus.In that after entering free text the dropdown is not showed.I want to show the dropdown when new element is created and press enter.

Anyone Pls help.

Regards,

Rekha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.In the magicsuggest.js,I have replaced the following code.

```
 if(inputValid === true && cfg.allowFreeEntries === true) {
                        obj[cfg.displayField] = obj[cfg.valueField] = freeInput.trim();
                        ms.addToSelection(obj);
                        ms.collapse(); // reset combo suggestions
                        ms.input.focus();
                    }

 if(inputValid === true && cfg.allowFreeEntries === true) {
                        obj[cfg.displayField] = obj[cfg.valueField] = freeInput.trim();
                        ms.addToSelection(obj);
                        ms.expand(); // reset combo suggestions
                        ms.input.focus();
                    }
```

I have removed ms.collapse and added ms.expand.